# Permission error on sqlite.py file in venv

Tags: python-3.x, linux, bash, apache, permissions

I need to launch a script like that from Apache2 on debian
`$pid = shell_exec(sprintf('nohup /bin/bash /home/debian/Desktop/Holibot/holi.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!'));`

The holi.sh just activate the venv and run the python script.

However an external lib (kerykeion) I've pip installed raises a **permission error 13 permission denied** on a sqlite.py file base it uses (for geonames fetching). But I have put chmod 777 rwxrwxrwx and chown www-data recursively everywhere in my folders/files of python project !!! The script .py run well with www-data user and crashes during execution with the error...

Full traceback :

```
2023-06-14 13:40:16,532 - KrInstance - ERROR - Error in fetching http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON: attempt to write a readonly database

Which error comes from

self.responses[cache_key] = cached_response
  File "/home/debian/Desktop/Holibot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests_cache/backends/sqlite.py", line 283, in __setitem__
    con.execute(
sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database
```

And when I run the script directly **with www-data it works without the perm error...**
`theo@x:/home/debian/Desktop/Holibot$ sudo -u www-data bash -c "/home/debian/Desktop/Holibot/holi.sh"`

I am going crazy ! Is it Apache which causes this issue? Why does it work when I run it myself...

Comment: Based on the error `sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database`. It seems that www-data does not have permission to the sqlite database that the script is writing to

Comment: As I mentioned "I have put chmod 777 rwxrwxrwx and chown www-data recursively everywhere in my folders/files of python project" and "And when I run the script directly with www-data it works without the perm error..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that a python lib created a folder in /var/www/html/ instead of /home/debian/Desktop/Holibot/ so the PWD variables was different !

I did successfully troubleshooted with

```
import traceback
print(traceback.format_exc())
```

And the www-data had no perm to "wx" in html/ folders which maybe a bad practice ? ...